# Как изменить язык в phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Напишите последовательность как изменить язык в phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

на главной странице phpmyadmin

[image]

Comment: У меня та только английский язык,а мне нужен русский

Comment: @ААА, спрашивайте конкретно, что вам нужно. Как спросили, так и ответили

Comment: Вот я зашел на главную страницу в раздел languare и там только язык english,как мне сделать русский язык

Answer (score 2):

- [вариант номер раз](http://wphello.ru/rusifikaciya-phpmyadmin.html)
- [вариант номер два](http://myrusakov.ru/phpmyadmin-russian.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь